# Extracting phrases from text strings

Tags: php, string, extract

Please I need to use php to extract phrases from a text shown below:

> Peter,
>
> please check your email for a document I sent, thanks.
>
> Mark,
>
> please I need you to fix my Toyota Camry, thanks.
>
> Mark,
>
> please go and pick up the kids from school, thanks.
>
> Jane,
>
> please go the shop and some items for the house, thanks.

What I need is to display only the phrases relating to Mark. Please note that in this example, Mark has only 2 messages and it could be more residing between Peter and Jane

```
<?php

$data = "

Peter, <br>

please check your email for a document I sent, thanks.<br>

Mark, <br>

please I need you to fix my Toyota Camry, thanks. <br>

Mark, <br>

please go and pick up the kids from school, thanks. <br>

Jane, <br>

please go the shop and some items for the house, thanks.

";

$start = 'Mark';

$end = 'thanks';

$startIndex = strpos($data, $start);

$endIndex = strpos($data, $end, $startIndex) + strlen($end);

$result = substr($data, $startIndex, $endIndex - $startIndex);

echo $result;

?>
```

This is what I tried but the result was only the first Phrase

> Mark, Please I need to fix my Toyota Camry, thanks.

But I need it to show the second or more phrases relating to Mark.

Please I need help to achieve this.

For this example I am expecting as follows:

> Mark, Please I need you to fix my Toyota Camry, thanks. Mark, Please
> go and pick up the kids from school, thanks.

Comment: You'll need to use a loop, to keep checking for further matches starting from (resp. after) the last position where you found a match ...

Comment: Thank you very much CBroe. I am new to php. Please can you tell me where to insert the loop code and how the code is written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a while loop to keep going, until the strpos to determine the start index returns false:

```
$start = 'Mark';

$end = 'thanks';

$fromPos = 0;

while(false !== ($startIndex = strpos($data, $start, $fromPos))) {

    $endIndex = strpos($data, $end, $startIndex) + strlen($end);

    $result = substr($data, $startIndex, $endIndex - $startIndex);

    $fromPos = $endIndex; // set the new position to search from
                          // on the next iteration

    echo $result ."<br><br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked as expected. My very best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can explode your string by `<br>` and search every two items for the key and append the next if found.

```
$input = explode("<br>", $yourtext);
$searchTerm = 'Mark,';
$output = [];
for ($index = 0; $index < count($input); $index += 2) {
    if (strpos($input[$index], $searchTerm) !== false) {
        if (isset($input[$index + 1])) $output[]=$input[$index + 1];
    }
}
```